# Selenium Java | Trouble finding/clicking button with xpath nested in class

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Problem:
I can't figure out how to click the specific button I need and how to make sure that button isn't highlighted.

1) On the main page, there is a button for each page. They all have their own close/report button.

2) I need to select ONLY non highlighted pages, and click THAT close button.

I can use this to click the button, but I don't know if it's highlighted or not.

```
By.xpath("//button[@type='button'])[8].click();
```

I tried doing something like this, but it didn't work:

```
By.xpath("//li[@class='media'] and //button[@type='button']").click();
```

Here is what each page looks like. Some are highlighted, some are in the class name.

```
<li class="media highlighted">
<div class="media-options">
  <button type="button" class="close" title="Close page">Delete this page</button>
  <button type="button" class="report" title="Report page">Report this page</button>
</div>
```

```
<li class="media">
<div class="media-options">
  <button type="button" class="close" title="Close page">Delete this page</button>
  <button type="button" class="report" title="Report page">Report this page</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For delete this button :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='media highlighted']//button[@class='close']"));
```

For Report this button :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='media highlighted']//button[@class='report']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to know whether an element is highlighted or not from its css class attributes.

```
String liClassAttribute = driver.findElements("//li[@class='media'][1]").getAttribute("class");
```

Here I have explained, how to get class attribute of first li item.

However as per your question, you need to click on non-highlighted items. So get a list of all list items, get class attribute for each item of li and if its not highlighted, you can act as per your requirement.

Pseudocode:

```
List<WebElement> liElementList = driver.findElement("//li[@class='media']);
for(WebElement elem : liElementList) {
    String liClassAttr = liElementList[0].getAttribute("class");
    if ( !liClass.contains("highlighted")){
         // you found the non-highlighted list item
         // act on it or ignore it based on your business logic.
    }
 }
```